# Nav2 Stack's Behavior tree (BT.CPP) version

Tags: ros-humble, nav2, release

I am working in ROS 2 Humble, Nav 2 Stack for my robot's navigation, Now i can see that BT.CPP has released it's latest version of 4.4 with lot of new features, May I know what is the supported version of BT.CPP in Nav 2 also need to know about the plan to upgrade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use v3.8 in Nav2 since its been stable and v4 has been under active development and bug fixing the last few months. Things are largely stable now and we do plan to move to v4.4 in January-February 2024 in conjunction with the BT.CPP maintainer, Davide Faconti.

v4.4 will be available for Jazzy and newer, but we cannot backport support for v4.4 since your BT XML files will require changes to work with v4 and there are other behavioral changes that cannot be backported to existing distributions since it would break everyone instantly.